# How to view and change kernel memory size?

Tags: kernel, memory

How can i view the kernel's share of memory on a machine? How can I increase it? What should I consider before doing it?

Comment: Please clarify what you mean by "the kernel's share".

Comment: Your question makes no sense: the kernel takes whatever memory it needs, no more, no less. Is there a specific feature you're trying to tune? (There are settings you can tune, but the defaults are right in >99.99% of use cases.)

Answer (score 4):

Memory for what?

You can adjust kernel parameters in /etc/sysctl.conf

try running

```
sysctl -a | egrep -i "(vm|page|mem|shm)"
```

for some example kernel memory-related parameters